# Chaining Angular Promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am having some trouble chaining promises in Angular. What I want to do is fetch my project object from the API, then check if the project owner has any containers, if they do, trigger the another `GET` to retrieve the container. In the end the container assigned to `scope` should either be null or the object retrieved from the API.

Right now, this example below resolves immediately to the second `then` function, and I get the error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$http.get('/api/projects/' + id).then(function (data) {
  $scope.project = data.project;
  return data.project;
}).then(function (project) {
  var containers = project.owner.containers;
  if (containers.length) {
    return $http.get('/api/containers/' + containers[0]);
  } else {
    return null
  }
}).then(function (container) {
  $scope.container = container;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out the data from passed into `then` is inside a field, so I needed to do

```
$scope.project = data.data.project;
return data.data.project;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code works, but what if the $http call fails because of a 404? Or you want to later want to add some extra business logic?

In general you want to handle 'negative' cases using a rejecting promise, to have more control over the chaining flow.

```
$http.get('/api/projects/' + id).then(function (data) {
  $scope.project = data.data.project;
  return data.data.project;
}).then(function (project) {
  var containers = project.owner.containers;
  if (containers.length) {
    return $q.reject('containers empty');
  }
  return $http.get('/api/containers/' + containers[0]);
}).then(function (container) {
  $scope.container = container;
}).except(function (response) {
  console.log(response); // 'containers empty' or $http response object
  $scope.container = null;
});
```